# «Кажется... ( ) ничего, зато...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

> Кажется, мы прогнали всю интеллигенцию ( ) ничего, зато у нас есть наша исконная самобытность и духовные скрепы!

Что поставить и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, можно попросту поставить **точку.** Например:

*Укатал ее проект. Ничего, зато повзрослеет.* [А. А. Голицын. Ящик. История одного шоу // «Волга», 2009]

Если всё же мы объединяем предложения в бессоюзное сложное, то ставим **тире:**

***Кажется, мы прогнали всю интеллигенцию – ничего, зато у нас есть наша исконная самобытность и духовные скрепы!***

> 2. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в ней выражено **противопоставление** по отношению к содержанию первой части (между частями можно вставить союз *но* или *а*)...

*В дождь материал чуть промокает, но ничего, зато подкладку выбрали толстую.* [Эдуард Лимонов. Подросток Савенко (1982)]

[Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы оформила этот текст так:

***Кажется, мы прогнали всю интеллигенцию? Ничего, зато у нас есть наша исконная самобытность и духовные скрепы!***

Пояснение

Как мне кажется, первое предложение должно быть **вопросительным**, в этом случае вся фраза звучит выразительно и очень иронично (что, разве прогнали?).

А вот в сложном предложении все это обозначить практически невозможно.

Comment: Да, так красивее получается... :)

Comment: "Кажется" в вопросительном предложении? Протестую. Это вводное слово употребляется при сообщении какой-либо информации. Кажется автору, а если он спрашивает, то о том, не кажется ли собеседнику: *[Тебе] кажется, что мы прогнали всю интеллигенцию?* И пропускать "что" крайне плохо.

Comment: Одиночный пикет?  Интересненько! Ну вот вам тогда пример.  ― Кажется, ты тоже успела хлебнуть, Таня? ― осторожно спросил Кянукук. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]   Аксенова уважаете? А пропускать "что" почему плохо? Здесь же  вводное слово, как вы только что утверждали.

Comment: Интересненько! И вы решили поставить меня в ступор примером, где оно вроде бы на месте. Но ни тут-то было! Разберу что угодно и выясню, в чём дело! Здесь вот что: *Кажется, ты тоже успела хлебнуть, Таня[, не так ли]?* Аксёнов опустил "не так ли". Можно ли так делать? Скорее всего, нет. В самом предложении нет вопросительной интонации, но оно так составлено, что понятно, что хотят услышать подтверждение. Здесь можно без "что", говорил про ваш пример. Дело в том, что "кажется" = "мне кажется", оно не подходит для вопросительной интонации!

Comment: Ок, просто у меня на слух "ни" звучало, хотелось сказать "ни" для усиления. Вроде бы всегда слышал только "ни" в этом выражении, так и написал. Люди порой говорят не так, как пишется.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, вы уж там с Аксеновым как-нибудь сами разберитесь.  Спокойной ночи и до новых встреч.

Comment: Уже разобрался. Не совсем у него правильно. Не должно быть вопросительного знака. Часто можно услышать что-то подобное: *Кажется, дождь начинается. Я прав? Кажется, пора домой, не так ли?* Такую структуру необходимо соблюдать. Но в таких сложных вещах легко ошибиться.